# Venice Airport Bus Tickets

Tags: public-transport, europe, italy, italian-residents, venice

I have to go from the Marco Polo airport to Mestre Teatro BNL.. This is around 25 minutes away. On Google maps, I see a bunch of busses for example Bus 15, 10, 25, 35.

But how much each individual ticket costs if we are travelling without any daily pass? We're 4 people. I read somewhere that the ticket is 1.5 euro but on another website, it stated 8 euros. How do I know if the buses mentioned above qualify for the smaller fare (1.5) or 8 euros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://ecommerce.atvo.it/ecommerce-fe/, a one way ticket from Marco Polo airport to Mestre - Corso del Popolo (one minute from Mestre Teatro BNL) costs 10 euros.